# Maximum light fixture wattage question

Tags: lighting, light-fixture

​I'm trying to switch the incandescent light bulbs in my living room to LED ones.​ I've noticed that originally all the light bulbs were 65W 620 lumen. I've bought four LED light bulbs ([http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00UKE5YAW?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o02_s00](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00UKE5YAW)) that are 100W equivalent. After I install all of them they won't light up so I'm guessing whether I've exceeded the maximum watts.

​I've unscrewed the light switch panel and it reads something like "600W max, 500W with one side removed, 400W with two sides removed" so I guess it should be able to fit 400W light bulbs.

So what went wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are these on a dimmer, perhaps? Dimmable LEDs need an LED-rated dimmer to be happy, generally. If the dimmer is old that usually means replacing it.

You have **not** increased the wattage. The Wattage is **15W** per bulb - the "equivalent wattage" is *marketing organic fertilizer* meant to convey the lumen output relative to an incandescent bulb. It has nothing to do with actual wattage.

You may have an issue where the base of the bulb is too fat, too soon for the fixture socket, so that no contact is being made to the center contact. Depending on how extreme this is it can sometimes be helped (circuit breaker for the circuit OFF, please) by gently, slightly, bending the center contact in the socket up just a bit - but if you overdo it you can snap the contact off, so don't overdo it.

Comment: Interestingly, I've tried to install the light bulbs again and it now works..